# angular2 and rxjs: ngIf according to a Subject

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've created this `Subject`:

```
private componentsState$: Subject<{[key: string]: boolean}> = new Subject();
```

I'm subscribing to it using `async` pipe into my template:

```
<div *ngIf="(componentsState$ | async).list" payment-list></div>
<div *ngIf="(componentsState$ | async).form" payment-form></div>
<div *ngIf="(componentsState$ | async).detail" payment-detail></div>
```

`payment-list`, `payment-form` and `payment-detail` are subcomponents are swapped according to `componentsState$` subject between each others.

on `onNgInit`:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.swapToList();
}
```

And,

```
swapToList(): void {
  this.swapComponent('list');
}

swapComponent(componentName: string): void {
  let componentsState = {
    'list': (): void => this.componentsState$.next(this.getListComponentState()),
    'form': (): void => this.componentsState$.next(this.getFormComponentState()),
    'detail': (): void => this.componentsState$.next(this.getDetailComponentState()),,
  };

  componentsState[componentName]();
}
```

And `getListComponentState`, returns the `key: boolean` object:

```
private getListComponentState(): {[key: string]: boolean} {
  return { list: true, form: false, detail: false};
}
```

And `getFormComponentState`

```
private getFormComponentState(): {[key: string]: boolean} {
  return { list: false, form: true, detail: false};
}
```

And `getDetailComponentState`

```
private getDetailComponentState(): {[key: string]: boolean} {
  return { list: false, form: false, detail: true};
}
```

Nevertheless, any component is shown when template is rendered. Any ideas?

I've to say, it fails only the first time the component parent component os loaded.

Comment: what does return `getFormComponentState` ?

Comment: I've added it on post.

Answer (score 3):

I've solved it using `BehaviorSubject` instead of `Subject`:

```
private componentsState$: BehaviorSubject<{[key: string]: boolean}> = new BehaviorSubject(this.getListComponentState());
```

So, then I'm able to set an initial value and avoid to call a `next()` on `onNgInit` method.